# The Hubble parameter of Randall-Sundrum model

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, string-theory, branes, supergravity

It’s mentioned in this paper

[On the cosmological constant problem and brane-world geometry](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Abe-Capistrano/publication/226132275_On_the_cosmological_constant_problem_and_brane-world_geometry/links/5451692a0cf2bf864cba92d6/On-the-cosmological-constant-problem-and-brane-world-geometry.pdf?origin=publication_detail)

that the Hubble parameter of the Randall-Sundram model is given by:

$$ H^2 = \frac{8\pi}{3m_{pl}^2} \rho + \frac{16\pi^2}{9m_{5}^6} \rho^2 $$

and the extra term on Friedmann equations that is quadratic in the energy density $\rho^2$ provides a deceleration scenario of the universe. The question here:

- Why or how $\rho^2$ term casues deceleration of the universe?
- How to derive the given Hubble parameter of the Randall-Sundram model:

[An Alternative to Compactification](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9906064)

[A Large Mass Hierarchy from a Small Extra Dimension](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905221)

Comment: Please do not link direct to paper (pdf, etc.).  Where possible link to the *abstract* page.

Comment: @StephenG. Okay, I edited this.